# Restrict user to access parent window without closing Child one

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have one JFrame which is parent one. Using one of the button from parent JFrame, opening new JFrame which is child window.

How can I restrict user to access parent window without closing Child one?

I can not use JDialog as having some dependency on JFrame.

Comment: *"I can not use JDialog as having some dependancy on JFrame."*  What?  A `JDialog` might have a parent or not.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: My Child wondow called from many places, and I have arround 23 child window which get called from diffrent places. If I make them as JDialog, then again I need to handle UI issue. Also testing is required. So I am just searching is it possible to achive same functionality using JFrame itself?

Comment: I still do not understand *"..I have arround 23 child window which get called from diffrent places.."* Does that mean 23 other windows can be on-screen at the same time?  That is definitely a case for an MDI (Multi-Document Interface).  If it is 'one at a time' you might have a static method to `getDialog(Component content)`..

Comment: `"If I make them as JDialog, then again I need to handle UI issue."` -- please translate this into English as it makes no sense. `"Also testing is required."` -- so fine, test. But test it as a JDialog. You seem to be doing nothing but throwing up obstructions in your way of using the right construct, and we can't help you if you do this. The solution is, was, and will be -- use a *modal* JDialog.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).

Quote:

> - Modal dialog box — A dialog box that blocks input to some other top-level windows in the application, except for windows created with the dialog box as their owner. The modal dialog box captures the window focus until it is closed, usually in response to a button press.
> - Modeless dialog box — A dialog box that enables you to operate with other windows while this dialog box is shown.

Also look at [JDialog#setModalityType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType%28java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29) and [Dialog.ModalityType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html). These will allow you to set the modality type of the dialog.

The available types are:

- **APPLICATION_MODAL**: An APPLICATION_MODAL dialog blocks all top-level windows from the same Java application except those from its own child
  hierarchy.
- **DOCUMENT_MODAL**: A DOCUMENT_MODAL dialog blocks input to all top-level windows from the same document except those from its own child
  hierarchy.
- **MODELESS**: MODELESS dialog doesn't block any top-level windows.
- **TOOLKIT_MODAL**: A TOOLKIT_MODAL dialog blocks all top-level windows run from the same toolkit except those from its own child hierarchy.